# How to select only one checkbox on mapped data in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In this case, I want to select only one checkbox which is if one checkbox is selected all others will be unchecked. So how it will work with react redux action and reducer

```
data:[
{id:1, name:apple, isChecked:false},
{id:2, name:banana, isChecked:false}
{id:3 ,name:mango, isChecked:false},
{id:4, name:grape, isChecked:false},
{id:5, name:carrot, isChecked:false},
]


 {data.map((item,index) => {
     <Checkbox onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)} checked={item.isChecked} />
 }}
```

Comment: You mention redux but there is no redux code here. How is this component supposed to interact with your redux state?

Answer (score 1):

Demo at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-violet-8qd6c?file=/src/App.js).

Simple `map` and changing the state of `data` will do the trick.

**Note:** Here, I've used simple `input` for checkboxes. You can use your component.

**Source:**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const defaultData = [
    { id: 1, name: "apple", isChecked: false },
    { id: 2, name: "banana", isChecked: false },
    { id: 3, name: "mango", isChecked: false },
    { id: 4, name: "grape", isChecked: false },
    { id: 5, name: "carrot", isChecked: false }
  ];
  const [data, setData] = useState(defaultData);

  function handleChange(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const modifiedData = [...data];
    modifiedData.map((item) => {
      item.isChecked = item.id === +value;
      return item;
    });
    setData(modifiedData);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <input
            type="Checkbox"
            value={item.id}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            checked={item.isChecked}
          />
          {item.name}
          <br />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general if you only want one item to be selected then you don't want an `isChecked` property on every item as there is too much room for error.  Instead you want a single property that stores the currently checked `id`.  This is true if using Redux or a local component state.

There's not a lot of info in your question, but you can handle most of the logic in Redux by dispatching a `toggleChecked` action with the `id` as the `payload`.

Here's an example reducer setup using Redux Toolkit.

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  items: [
    { id: 1, name: "apple" },
    { id: 2, name: "banana" },
    { id: 3, name: "mango" },
    { id: 4, name: "grape" },
    { id: 5, name: "carrot" }
  ],
  selectedId: undefined
};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "checkboxes",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // select this id and deselect all others
    // action.payload is the id
    selectId: (state, action) => {
      state.selectedId = action.payload;
    },
    // either select or deselect this id
    // action.payload is the id
    toggleChecked: (state, action) => {
      const isChecked = state.selectedId === action.payload;
      if (isChecked) {
        state.selectedId = undefined; // uncheck
      } else {
        state.selectedId = action.payload; // check
      }
    },
    // action.payload is an item with name and id properties
    addItem: (state, action) => {
      state.items.push(action.payload);
    }
    // can add other actions like remove, rename, etc.
  }
});

export const { selectId, toggleChecked, addItem } = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;
```

Now your component becomes very simple.  We select the options and the current `selectedId` from the Redux state.  We see if each `item` is selected by comparing its `id` to the `selectedId`.  We handle the change of each checkbox by dispatching the `toggleChecked` action with this `id`.

```
import { toggleChecked } from "../store/slice";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Checkbox } from "@material-ui/core";

const CheckboxSelect = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { items, selectedId } = useSelector((state) => state.checkboxes);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(({ id, name }) => (
        <div key={id}>
          <Checkbox
            checked={id === selectedId}
            onChange={() => dispatch(toggleChecked(id))}
          />
          {name}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CheckboxSelect;
```

[Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-select-one-checkbox-rp1xb?file=/src/components/App.tsx)

Comment: Thanks for a really great answer! Do you recommend the same approach for handling multiple items selection (by making `state.selectedId` an array)? How will you compute the `checked` prop then? Something like `checked={selectedId.includes(id)}`? Or maybe in this case it is better to take a different approach, like adding an `isSelected` property on every item?

Comment: Both of your ideas for multiple items are good.  An `isSelected` `boolean` can be easier to toggle so I generally prefer that, but an `array` is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  /* declare a state containing all of checkbox's data */
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "apple", isChecked: false },
    { id: 2, name: "banana", isChecked: false },
    { id: 3, name: "mango", isChecked: false },
    { id: 4, name: "grape", isChecked: true },
    { id: 5, name: "carrot", isChecked: false }
  ]);

  const handleChecked = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.name);

    const res = data.map((d) => {
      if (d.id.toString() === e.target.name)
        return { ...d, isChecked: !d.isChecked };

      return d;
    });

    setData(res);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {data.map((d) => (
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={d.isChecked}
          // name is `d.id` so that we can know which checkbox to change via `e.target.name` in the handler function
          name={d.id}
          onChange={handleChecked}
          key={d.id}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is a [Code Sandbox link to a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-smoke-l0d3i?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

No, need to use map while update just filter the record and update. Try this hope it will work.

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: "apple", isChecked: true },
      { id: 2, name: "banana", isChecked: false },
      { id: 3, name: "mango", isChecked: false },
      { id: 4, name: "grape", isChecked: false },
      { id: 5, name: "carrot", isChecked: false }
    ]
  };

// onChange event handler  
  handleChange = e => {
    let arr = this.state.data.find(item => item.id == e.target.dataset.id);
    arr.isChecked = !arr.isChecked;
    this.setState({ ...this.state.date, arr });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map((item, index) => (
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            data-id={item.id}
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            checked={item.isChecked}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Note: pass  `data-id={item.id}` in checkbox element.It will help to get data id `e.target.dataset.id` in onchange handler event, by this way can filter particular record and update.